# DetoxRuntimeError: Detox instance has not been initialized

Tags: ios, react-native, detox

After updating to react-native 0.63.3 and xcode 12.0.1 the tests are not working anymore. First had some issues building detox but that was solved. Now this error is there and I cannot go further:

```
DetoxRuntimeError: Detox instance has not been initialized
HINT: Make sure to call detox.init() before your test begins
```

detox.init() is being called and I can see it in the logs.

This is my init.js

```
import { device } from 'detox';

const detox = require('detox');

const config = require('../package.json').detox;
const adapter = require('detox/runners/jest/adapter');
const specReporter = require('detox/runners/jest/specReporter');
const assignReporter = require('detox/runners/jest/assignReporter');

jest.setTimeout(180000);

jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(adapter);

jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(specReporter);

jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(assignReporter);

beforeAll(async () => {
  await detox.init(config, { launchApp: false });
  const permissions = {
    notifications: 'NO',
    camera: 'NO',
  };
  await device.launchApp({ permissions });
});

beforeEach(async () => {
  await adapter.beforeEach();
});

afterAll(async () => {
  await adapter.afterAll();
  await detox.cleanup();
});
```

My environment:

React-Native: 0.63.3 Detox: 17.10.3 xcode: 12.0.1 iOS: 14.0

Running on ios.sim.debug

Answer (score 0):

After long search I have found out that the actual tests are in a submodule/subrepo of the project. The tests are triggered from the app root level. Before the update even those tests were triggered correctly. Now, they only work if I move them to from the submodule level to the app root level

Comment: care to elaborate? i am encountering similar issue. so what do you mean by moving app the root level? which files? thanks!

Comment: it was a stupid issue on my side. Our app structure:
-app-root
---->subModule1
---->subModule2
---->subModule3
---->subModule3
---->subModule4

We trigger the tests from the app-root level but the tests are for each subModule in the right folders in that module. The error was that I have updated detox only on the app-root level. Forgot to do it on the submodules.
After I have moved one test from the subModule level to the app-root level the test was working fine. After updating all subModules to the new version of detox, everything was fine. Hope it helps you